# touchend and pointerup events in react native webview (with expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I am having trouble getting the `touchend` and `pointerup` events to work in my web application that is running inside a react-native-webview component in an Expo managed project (barebones workflow). Can someone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and make these events function correctly?

Comment: Use the onTouchEnd and onPointerUp props instead. Or, check that your webview is correctly configured to handle touch events. `allowsTouchEvents: true`